# Azure AWS cognito user pool analog

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito, azure-ad-b2c

I was using AWS cognito as API for registration in my application. Is there any similar analog to Cognito in Azure. I am looking for some API in Azure where I can host users in Azure which will register in my application.

I saw some Azure AD B2C, but I am not sure about API. Is it possible to integrate auth in my application with Azure B2C or maybe there is another service which is more suitable for this case?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: AWS to Azure services comparison: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/aws-professional/services#authentication-and-authorization

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD and AD B2C have no authentication API.

You authenticate using a Microsoft-supplied login page.